# Facebook Like throwing error when using older version of facebook app (version 1.8.3)

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Im using facebook SDK 3.5.

And implemented the facebook like using Open Graph.

Facebook like is wokring fine when device have latest version of facebook app( It's wokring from **facebook 1.9.8 to facebook current version**).

I have htc x-one device it has throwing the following error.

[image]

If i **update my facebook app** it's working fine. But, i dont want to force the user to update the facebook app which is already installed.

How can i solve this issue. Kindly share your ideas.

Thanks!.

Comment: what does your request look like? any special permission request?

Comment: I requested "publish_actions" permission.